# Math Type Integration in Tiny Mce

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I have been having a problem to integrate Math type to Tiny Mce. I have done a lot of research and all to no avail. The major problem is i cannot find a direct link to download the "tiny_mce_wiris" add on directly. And again, i will need a step by step integration procedure. I will really appreciate a simple and clear response from anyone. Thanks in advance
Note: I am not using any language technology. Just a normal html file displayed in browser.